# How to use .Wrap option in iCarousel library by swift?

Tags: ios, swift, icarousel

I need to set .Wrap option in iCarousel by swift.

This is my code.

```
func carousel(carousel: iCarousel!, valueForOption option: iCarouselOption, withDefault value: CGFloat) -> CGFloat

    switch (option)
    {
        case .Spacing:
            return value * 1.1
        case .Wrap:
            return true 
            // Error cannot convert return expression
        default:
            return value
    }

}
```

But i cant return true on .Wrap option.

How can i fix this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Nick should probably put this in the documentation, for swift users, the correct way to enable wrap is as follow:

```
func carousel(carousel: iCarousel, valueForOption option: iCarouselOption, withDefault value: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
 switch option {
  case .Wrap:
   return 1.0 // note: 0.0 if you want to disable wrap
  default:
   return value
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For letting your code atleast run (though with a warning), you may try doing this:

```
case .Wrap:
    return true as! CGFloat
```

Hope it helps you in atleast getting the app running for the time being! 
(and you may mark this answer helpful if it helps.)

Though for a better permanent solution, you may contact iCarousel team.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me.

```
func carousel(_ carousel: iCarousel, valueFor option: iCarouselOption, withDefault value: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        if (option == .spacing) {
            return value * 1.1
        }
        if (option == .wrap) {
            return 0.0 // wrap disabled
        }
        return value

    }
```